How to separate two Facebook accounts
I have two Facebook accounts: one on my hotmail account, and another one on a gmail account. On both accounts I use different aliases but something has gone wrong recently: when using my gmail account, I get logged in under the alias of my hotmail account.
Apparently somewhere both accounts have been linked to each other. How can I know where that is and how can I separate both accounts again?
Thanks in advance
